# Azure Cognitive Search query specific data source

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have a Azure Cognitive Search set up with two DataSources, two Indexers indexing those DataSources and one Index.

I'd like to be able to able to query/filter by DataSource. Is that possible?

Comment: Not by data source but you should be able to filter/query by fields populated by the data source.

Comment: Fields are all the same in both DataSources so there is no way for me to tell which data source they came from. Any ideas? I want to avoid having multiple Cognitive Search services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off of @Derek Legenzoff serve this is how I did it...

1. Add all your `datasources`
2. Create `skillsets` for each one data source with the following skill

   ```
   {
       "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ConditionalSkill",
       "name": "#1",
       "description": "",
       "context": "/document",
       "inputs": [
           {
               "name": "condition",
               "source": "= true"
           },
           {
               "name": "whenTrue",
               "source": "= 'Production'" //name of your environment
           },
           {
               "name": "whenFalse",
               "source": "= ''"
           }
      ],
      "outputs": [
          {
              "name": "output",
              "targetName": "Env"
          }
      ]
   }
   ```
3. Create single `index` for your data model and add a `Env` field, and it's filterable and queryable
4. Create `indexers` for each one of your data sources that point to the `index` from step 3 and `datasource` from step 1
5. IMPORTANT: make sure you indexers have the following code in the definition.

   ```
    "outputFieldMappings": [
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "/document/Env",
            "targetFieldName": "Env"
        }
    ],
   ```

This will connect the product of the `skill` to the `index`

Comment: Great! Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. You'd just need to find a way to get a field in the index that contains the name of the data source. The best way to do this depends on the data source you're using--for example, if you're using a SQL data source, you might just be able to edit the query to return the value whereas that wouldn't work for blob storage.

Another option that would work for all data sources would be to include a skillset with a [conditional skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-conditional) which you can use to set a default value for a field.

Comment: It's a simple azure sql server table. What's the simplest way tell the index to keep track of the datasource?